# File structure inside a smartcard

Tags: smartcard

I bought a smart card that it support java. 
How I can understand the file structure inside it?

I mean did all cards have `Master File` , `Dedicated Files` and `Elementary Files` inside? or some card have a tree-shape structure like this?

How can I recognize this cards from others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the card is ISO 7816-4 compliance then it will have MF,DF,EF structure.
To know the whole file structure if any in card then u will need specification of card from the card vendor.

Comment: Is there any specific command to select `MF`? we can select card manager and other applets with `00 A4 04 00 LC | AID`. we use this command to select `MF`, `DF` and `EF` too? if yes, what data must put instead of `AID` in the command?

Comment: To select MF you can use a0 a4 00 00 02 3F00 where 3f00 is MF, you can use this command to select DF,EF too,just change the data part :)
These commands are ISO 7816 commands.To know more about commands .Please refer [link](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/100900_100999/100977/08.14.00_60/ts_100977v081400p.pdf),For commands goto page41.

Comment: Excuse me dear Anurag, but , why we use this command? this MF,DF and EF are something like directories in windows?

Comment: Yes this is a smartcard file structure to store data in EF.For More info abt these commands please refer ISO7816-4,its paid doc thats why i have given the refrence of free doc and that was abt SIM card but commands are same.

Comment: And when we install an applet, if we don't use select APDU command, it will upload and install in MF by default?

Comment: NO NO, it will go to the card manager your applet doesnt stored in any EF, when u send load/install its the data of cap/ijc file that you are loading on card and card manager will verify load/install commands and will install the applet on card's memory[EEPROM area].
And FYI...u cant store anything in MF/DF only these are like window folders to store data EF is used..

Comment: So what is these MF,EF and DF? Directories on ROM? Can I add or remove a EF,DF or MF? what is in this directories? :(

Comment: These MF/DF/EF uses eeprom area to store data,lets suppose u developed some app to store data that can be read by 3rd party but u dont want to give access to your applet so u can store data in EF and let them read/write.

Comment: I can't understand, :| sorry! I select card manager, and upload my apps on EEPROM, right? the third party select my apps and use my apps, what is the role of MF/DF/EF here? when I select them? before Installing apps? why? Am I idiot? :D

Comment: there is no need to select any ME/DF/EF before installing apps, before installing app u select card manager not the files.
your app is secure u dont want to share AID of ur applet to 3rd party or lets say u dont want to give access to ur app, then storing data in an EF is useful or lets say ur card is going to be use in any device.
Lets take an ex of SIM card it will be used in mobile phone and mobile phone dont know what apps are there in card,so mobile will read EF to read useful data.

Comment: DF is not used to store data the structure is like this MF can have multiple DFs and DFs can have multiple EFs.and EFs are use to store data.

Comment: when I upload and install an applet (until now), after installing, any body can access to my applets. what's the meaning of that?

Comment: Its just ur wish if u want to give access to someone else or not u can implement some commands like verify before using ur applet this makes ur app secure

Comment: And someone can only access ur app if he/she knows the aid and the apdu commands accepted by ur applet.

Comment: Is this right? --> when I want to upload an app, I select card manager and send install command. and my app will upload and install in EEPROM. and in my app, if I want to use memory , there is different sections, and I can use select MF/DF and EF in the app-source-code to go through the memory. Is this right? if no, when I use select MF/DF/EF? and why?!!!!

Comment: Yes u r absolutely right and u can use persistent array as well to store data in app.

Comment: You need to summarise these comments into your answer